# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql

Is there a 64bit version of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

I downloaded the 32bit/64bit version of SQL 2008 Developer R2 and it still installed into the Program Files (x86)\ file location.

Answer (score 2):

I can see a separate version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en)

[SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe]

Comment: That looks like the free management studio for SQL Server Express, I'm not sure that's the same as the regular version.